# IE8: Limit in Number of ActiveX controls per page?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I'm displaying data in a html table (datatables jquery plugin). One column displays the data in an activex control (IE) or plugin (Firefox).

I now have an issue when there are like 100 rows or more in IE, meaning the page takes very long to load or will not load at all (crash, unresponsive for minutes).

In firefox, the problem occurs too but you need like 500 rows or more to make it appear.
Does IE8 have some kind of limit on how many activex controls can be displayed?
If I remove the activex the page loads instantly.

Any ideas?
ActiveX is 3rd party. Can't change it.

Comment: I don't think there is a hard coded limit, but I think you're screwed if you can't change the control.  Is there a way to use it that doesn't require instantiating it a bazillion times per page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by limiting the amount of records per page (this can be configured) and using server-side processing feature of datatables. server-side processing needs a bit of work to get it to run properly. I return JSON from the server and use the fnRowCallback function to load the plugin/control.

Note that server-side processing is needed because of how the plugin work(ed). I think the newest release has improvements that that would solve the issue without server-side processing

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to make IE or Firefox limit that automatically, but you could probably change the way your page displays to implement some form of paging where the rows not shown don't load the activex control.

It might take a bit of doing on the javascript side, but it'd almost definitely be easier than trying to manage it with a plugin, extension, or browser configuration -- particularly since even if you could find a way you'd still need to deploy that to any machines needing to use the system.

Comment: The Problem is, that this Control/plugin is loaded by JavaScript. As mentioned i use jquery Datatables plugin but the issue if I use AJAX/Server-side-processing I would need to retrun javascript in the JSOn object. Don't think that actually works.

Comment: I haven't used the datatables plugin, so I don't know exactly what you'd need to do to enable some form of paging; I do think that's your best bet, however, is to control how many plugin instances are run at a time yourself. You are not going to be able to expect the browser to do it for you.